# "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed" при проведении миграции

Tags: mysql, база-данных, django, innodb, myisam

Раньше в таблице `attribute_values` было `int` поле `attribute_id`. Хочу преобразовать его в `ForeignKey` к таблице `attributes`, но получаю ошибку `"Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed"` (также таблицы раньше были `MyIsam`, переделал их в `InnoDB`).

Миграция выглядит так:

```
    operations = [
        migrations.RemoveField(
            model_name='attributevalue',
            name='attribute_id',
        ),
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='attributevalue',
            name='attribute',
            field=models.ForeignKey(blank=True, null=True, on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.SET_NULL, to='attributes.attribute'),
        ),
    ]
```

**atrributes**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**attribute_values**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: *Раньше в таблице `attribute_values` было int поле `attribute_id`.* Вот в упор не вижу такого поля. Равно как и не вижу поля `attributes.attribute`, на которое Вы пытаетесь ссылаться в коде (может, нужно ссылаться на `attributes.id`?).

Comment: *Вот в упор не вижу такого поля.* - было. Но миграция уже удалила его (`RemoveField`). *может, нужно ссылаться на attributes.id* - точно. сейчас попробую..

Comment: `Related model 'attributes.id' cannot be resolved`

Comment: Ну смотрите, как оно там у фреймворка обзывается. Ибо в SQL коде было бы `ALTER TABLE attribute_values  ADD COLUMN attribute INT, ADD FOREIGN KEY (attribute) REFERENCES attributes (id)`.

Comment: Ух. Спасибо. Как бы вручную не пришлось писать миграции эти..